# Installed Xen and now computer won't boot

Tags: boot, 19.10, xen

I recently installed Xen on Ubuntu  19.10. When I rebooted my computer to use it Grub automatically booted as usual, but this time I got the error code on my main Samsung 1TB hard drive that the command hwmatch was unknown and my computer kept on rebooting. How can I fix this without doing a full reset?

Comment: Since Ubuntu was working, wouldn't this be better suited for Xen Forums?

Comment: Right, but how do I get to Xen Fourms?

Comment: http://discussions.zoho.com/xenforum#Forum/xen-users

Comment: The only website that I find when I search up "Xen virtual machine forums" is a Wiki page and an Ubuntu Help website. Neither of which have a forums page.